# Facebook Graph API: Get all posts from all the pages the user likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I want to get all the posts from all the pages from the user /me/home feed.
Right now Facebook is deciding for the user what posts will get to the feed and which ones will not.
For example, if the user is subscribed (likes) 100 pages and all 100 of them posts an update the user feed will not show all 100 of them, only a portion of updates that it thinks important. Neither the API.

Is it possible to get all updates using the Graph api (like a regular timeline)?

Comment: You can't get them with this way. Only way is to get all posts from each fanpage - page by page. What is the reason that you want them in one call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try FQL, for example:

```
{"query1":"SELECT type,post_id,created_time,actor_id,target_id,message,attachment.media,attachment.caption,attachment.name,attachment.description,attachment.fb_checkin,likes.count,likes.user_likes,likes.can_like,comment_info,description FROM stream WHERE filter_key='pp' AND created_time<now() ORDER BY created_time DESC","query2":"SELECT id,name,pic FROM profile WHERE id IN (SELECT actor_id,target_id FROM #query1)"}
```

**The keyword was filter_key='pp', means that you want to get all page's news feed.**

I have no idea it will include ALL of 100 pages on real time, however this should be enough to achieve your goal. One more point, news feed have 1 week limitation, means that you cannot query older than 1 week's news feed.

**Update:**

https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?filter=pp is alternative way if you don't want to use FQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following FQL in your https request to get the list of all likes paginated

```
SELECT src_big, src_small, owner,caption FROM photo WHERE object_id IN (SELECT object_id FROM like WHERE user_id == me() LIMIT  10 OFFSET  8 )
```